# preg_replace pattern doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove some part from a SQL WHERE query. Although on `Regexpal` I have no problem with my pattern, when I place the expression into `preg_replace` it does NOT work.

An example of original not modified query WHERE part:

```
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (800,801) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'service_photo' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_meta_partner_subscription_level' )
```

My code and pattern:

```
$where = preg_replace("(AND \( wp_term_relationships\.term_taxonomy_id IN \([0123456789,]*\) \))", "", $where);
    return $where;
```

Do you have any idea what do I wrong?

PHP: 5.4.19

thanks

Comment: It works for me - have you assigned that string to `$where` variable? Why do you return it, you can echo it to check

Comment: My result is `WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'service_photo' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_meta_partner_subscription_level' )`

Comment: Your regex works fine here. Don't you have any extra  spaces or line feed in your original string?

Comment: Yes, I echoed the $where string and in the soure code view it contains several linebreaks
see the image: http://tinypic.com/r/2w5kjtj/8

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code showing your regex usage in PHP:

```
$re = "/(AND \\( wp_term_relationships\\.term_taxonomy_id IN \\([0-9,]*\\) \\))/"; 
$str = "WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (800,801) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'service_photo' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_meta_partner_subscription_level' )"; 

$str = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/eL5mJ6/3).

`[0123456789,]` can be safely replaced with `[0-9,]`.

Comment: Regex101 is a great tip, thank you. Your code works like a charm, but as I detected my $where string contains linebreaks. Could you please help me to create a patter in this case? see pic.: http://tinypic.com/r/2w5kjtj/8